# Any research paper on stop loss?

Tags: equities, backtesting, research

Has there been any rigorous study on stop loss ? When to apply it?

Has it been shown to work through proper statistical backtests?

I am interested in Equities, preferably European stocks.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, welcome to quant.SE and thanks for your question.  I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: @Siddharth: You can accept the answer if you are satisfied by it :-)

Answer (score 11):

I find this one very helpful:

[Re-Examining the Hidden Costs of the Stop-Loss
by Wilson Ma, Guy Morita, Kira Detko](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1123362)

Abstract:

> In this paper, we present general implications of the impact of
>   stop-losses to future returns. The use of stop-losses change return
>   distributions, but not in the way that one would typically expect. We
>   find that while stop-losses can reduce position volatility, hidden
>   costs offset perceived benefits in terms of altering future returns.
>   Use of both stop-losses and profit-taking stops separately or in
>   conjunction offer no statistically significant difference in expected
>   return but have a meaningful impact in returns with drift, as the
>   expected return converges to that of the underlying.